# How to remove the Outlook 2010 icon from tray?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, notification-area

How do I remove the Outlook 2010 icon from my Windows 7 system tray / notification area?

Just for clarification: i really mean 'remove' and not 'hide'.

I have the icon in the taskbar and I don't need to see a second redundant Outlook icon in my tray.[image]

Comment: I've been trying to do this myself.  There's sure as hell no options for it...

Comment: There's an option in Options -> Mail -> Message Arrival called "Show an envelope icon in the taskbar". I have it unchecked and it still shows up... SMH

Comment: @Jason - That is for when new mail arrives, not the actual Outlook icon that sits in the taskbar.

Answer (score 3):

Right click taskbar and select properties.  Under taskbar tab select "customize" then select which icons you want to show in system tray.

Comment: This only hides the icon from the direct view; when clicking the tray arrow, it is still there. Any alternatives?

Comment: @Aron Rotteveel I have been looking through the registry for the specific key related to that icon but I cannot find it.  Get into the registry and search `NotificationArea` and see what comes up, you might be able to figure out what key to change if you spend enough time changing values.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to right-click the icon and select "Hide when minimized", that way you won't have two icons at the same time. I know that's not a perfect solution.

Another option is to remove the taskbar itself through a registry hack. See this [Howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/completely-disable-the-system-tray-on-windows-vista-xp/) article for more information.

I cannot find anything in the registry that allows me to **disable** the actual icon *on its own*.

Answer (score 0):

It is an all or nothing situation in that you can hide the whole notification tray (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779143(WS.10).aspx), but you can't hide individual items in the tray.

Answer (score 0):

I found what seems to work – for me at least – at in [KnockOut](http://sunflowerhead.com/software/knockout/).  It allows many controls of the Outlook process and icons.

Comment: And does it allow to remove the icon?

Comment: KnockOut doesn't allow you to hide the Outlook tray icon. It only hides the New Mail tray icon, which you can easily do without knockout (just right-click the outlook tray icon & disable new mail alert). The other Outlook tray icon is still there.